# Передача в колбек функцию текущее состояние переменной

Tags: javascript, promise

в js использую обещания на основе библиотеки when.js(cujojs/when). Но от других решений Promises/A+ не сильно отличается(кроме jquery конечно)

При обходе списка элементов for-ом

```
function test(arr) {
   for (var key in arr) {
      var obj = new SomeObject(arr[key]);
      var promise_1 = getAjax('site1', obj);
      var promise_2 = getAjax('site2', obj);
      //ожидаю исполнение двух обещаний и потом ответы передаю в обработчик
      when.join(promise_1, promise_2)
          .spread(function (site_data_1, site_data_2) {

         //тут обращаюсь к obj 
         //НО обьект уже не тот который был при создании promise

      });
   }
}
```

Тоесть вся соль в том что при синхронном подходе obj будет текущим относительно итераций, но так как сначала проходит цикл а потом только сработает обработчик, то обработчик будит иметь дело только с последним состоянием переменной obj.

Надеюсь не сильно запутал простым вопросом. Мне нужно как то сделать замыкание таким образом что бы обработчик запомнил текущее состояние переменной obj.

Как сделать это некрасиво я уже знаю :) 
Знаю JavaScript силен, покажите как правильно это нужно решать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На эти грабли рано или поздно натыкается практически каждый разработчик JS. Проблема в том, что в JS, в отличии от C++, например, блоки кода в if/while/for и.т.д. не образуют новый scope, а используют scope функции в которой они находятся. Решение -- создать новый scope с помощью промежуточной функции и в ней уже создать замыкание:

```
for (var key in arr) {
   var obj = new SomeObj(key);
   var closure = (function(x) { return function() { alert(x); } })(obj);
   setTimeout(closure, 1000);
}
```

Comment: все хорошо, но порядок хаотичный выходит, это можно как то исправить?

Comment: @duhon, порядок чего?